# How should I cycle my game to be more scalable?

Tags: c#, multiplayer, multithreading

I'm trying to improve my game emulator so it can handle more users. I currently have one separate thread and execute all processing there.

The cycles processes players and rooms, rooms are individual maps that users can belong to, with other users where they can walk, talk and interact with each other

Currently my game server starts having issues where there are more than 2,000 users online, or when a single room has more than 60 users inside it.

Here is the main game cycle

```
private Task _gameCycle;
private int _cycleSleepTime = 25;

public Game()
{
    _cycleActive = true;

    _gameCycle = new Task(GameCycle);
    _gameCycle.Start();
}

private void GameCycle()
{
    while (_cycleActive)
    {
        Root.GetGame().GetRoomManager().OnCycle();
        Root.GetGame().GetPlayerManager().OnCycle();

        Thread.Sleep(_cycleSleepTime);
    }
}
```

RoomManager's OnCycle:

```
var sinceLastTime = DateTime.Now - _cycleLastExecution;

if (sinceLastTime.TotalMilliseconds >= 500)
{
    _cycleLastExecution = DateTime.Now;

    foreach (var room in _rooms.Values.ToList())
    {
        if (room.isCrashed)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (room.ProcessTask == null || room.ProcessTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            room.ProcessTask = new Task(room.ProcessRoom);
            room.ProcessTask.Start();
            room.IsLagging = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            room.IsLagging++;

            if (room.IsLagging >= 30)
            {
                room.isCrashed = true;
                UnloadRoom(room.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PlayerManager's OnCycle:

```
if (_clientPingStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 30000)
{
    _clientPingStopwatch.Restart();

    var toPing = new List<IGameClient>();

    foreach (var client in _clients.Values.ToList())
    {
        if (client.GetConnection().PingCount < 6)
        {
            client.GetConnection().PingCount++;

            toPing.Add(client);
        }
        else
        {
            lock (_timedOutConnections.SyncRoot)
            {
                _timedOutConnections.Enqueue(client);
            }
        }
    }

    var start = DateTime.Now;

    foreach (var client in toPing.ToList())
    {
        try
        {
            client.SendPacket(new PongComposer());
        }
        catch
        {
            lock (_timedOutConnections.SyncRoot)
            {
                _timedOutConnections.Enqueue(client);
            }
        }
    }
}

if (_timedOutConnections.Count < 1)
{
    return;
}

lock (_timedOutConnections.SyncRoot)
{
    while (_timedOutConnections.Count > 0)
    {
        IGameClient client = null;

        client = (IGameClient)_timedOutConnections.Dequeue();

        if (client != null)
        {
            client.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Each room has its own task (thread). It processes a lot, user movement, chat messages, items, status updates. I figured rather than waiting for each room to process in RoomManager's OnCycle, use a new thread and try to process multiple at the same time, after all the server is multi-core.

Room's ProcessRoom

```
public void ProcessRoom()
{
    if (isCrashed || mDisposed)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        if (GetRoomUserManager().GetRoomUsers().Count == 0)
        {
            IdleTime++;
        }
        else if (IdleTime > 0)
        {
            IdleTime = 0;
        }

        if (Promotion != null && Promotion.HasExpired)
        {
            EndPromotion();
        }

        if (IdleTime >= 60 && Promotion == null)
        {
            Root.GetGame().GetRoomManager().UnloadRoom(Id);
            return;
        }

        GetRoomItemHandler().OnCycle();
        GetRoomUserManager().OnCycle();
        GetRoomUserManager().SerializeStatusUpdates();
        GetWired().OnCycle();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.Exception(e);
        OnRoomCrash(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are those "issues" you are talking about? Did you already use a profiler to find out if you have any performance bottlenecks unrelated to how you handle threads?

Comment: Yes I did profile a little - it doesn't really matter how many users are online that number can scale pretty high so it seems, the issue is there are a lot of users in one room, and that room holds up everything in that one room. I was thinking of running all 3 things that get processed in the Room.ProcessTask to 3 process tasks, maybe it would allow the room to be processed faster and avoid blocking?

Comment: 1. Remove all of the `.ToList()` in your loop; 2. Use `Task.Delay()` instead of `Thread.Sleep()`; 3. Use `Task.Run()` to create a `Task` instead of `new Task`; 4. Use `ConcurrentQueue<T>` instead of the combination of `lock` + `Queue<T>`

Comment: @AshKetchum So the problem is that whatever your `Room` class does doesn't scale? Perhaps you have some algorithms in there where the runtime complexity scales very badly with the number of users in there?

Comment: @mr5 if you illustrate those tips with a code example this could make a good answer for users to vote up. :)